# What is the most efficient way to implement table which stores sparse data in C#

Tags: c#, sparse-matrix

I have a DataTable which stores very sparse data, something like:

```
   P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 ...
J1 1  1
J2    1  1
J3             1
.
.
.
```

The number of rows and columns might reach over 10^8.

How can I store this data in more efficient way?

Comment: Are you only storing 1's, or other data, and how do you need to retrieve the data afterwards? Aggregation, direct lookup?

Comment: What kind of density is expected? It looks like this is a large matrix with values running down the diagonal? Can it be optimized for a special-case (e.g. is it solved?) or must it remain general enough for a "non sparse" matrix?

Answer (score 2):

If your disk file system supports [Sparse files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) you can create an empty file, mark it sparse, and then resize it to `rows * colums * datasize`.

Then it's a matter of accessing the data by [row][column], where the offset can be calculated with:

```
offset = ((columns.length * (row-1)) + column) * datasize
```

There is some overhead with sparse files as well regarding allocation where it typically allocated pages of 16-64kb, but depending on how your data clusters it might very well work.

Answer (score 0):

First, get rid of the DataTable for those counts of data. Its memory usage is way to huge here.

If your data are always 0/1, the most efficient way should be a bit-mask.

If your data are not only 0/1, create a structure that abstracts all your columns.

Here's a conceptional prototype of that data structure.

```
class MyData {
    public MyData(int[] columns, object[] data) {
        _columns = columns;
        _data = data;
    }

    int[] _columns;
    object[] _data;

    public object this[int column] {
        get {
            int index = IndexOf(column);
            return index != -1 ? _data[index] : null;
        }
    }

    private int IndexOf(int column) {
        for (int i = 0; i < _columns.Length; i++)
            if (_columns[i] == column)
                return i;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

You could additionally save the memory for the _columns by applying the flyweight pattern.

Hope this helps

Comment: Bit-masks are only going to be more beneficial down to ~12% density (ignoring book-keeping overheads of other approaches and only dealing with booleans). That is, they can be good for compacting but are, by themselves, stuck at O(n), where n is the number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of [prior art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Storing_a_sparse_matrix) in storing spare matrices efficiently.

A common approach is known as 'List of Lists'. For example, Python has a memory efficient way of storing spare matrices as '[Row-based linked list sparse matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html)'.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution depends on how you are going to use it, but if it does not need to be serialized you could consider using a nested dictionary like this:

```
  using System.Collections.Generic;

  public class SparseMatrix<T>: Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, T>>
  {
    public void Add(int p, int j, T value)
    {
      Dictionary<int, T> jdic;
      if (!TryGetValue(p, out jdic))
      {
        jdic = new Dictionary<int, T>();
        Add(p, jdic);
      }
      jdic[j] = value;
    }

    public T query(int p, int j)
    {
      Dictionary<int, T> jdic;
      if (TryGetValue(p, out jdic))
      {
        T val;
        if (jdic.TryGetValue(j, out val))
          return val;
      }

      return default(T);
    }
  }
```

You can use it, in your example with a boolean like so:

```
  using Xunit;

  public class TestSparseBoolMatrix
  {
    [Fact]
    public void TestSBM()
    {
      SparseMatrix<bool> matrix = new SparseMatrix<bool>();

      matrix.Add(2, 4, true);
      matrix.Add(7, 3, true);

      bool NotSet = matrix.query(1, 1);
      bool isSet = matrix.query(2, 4);

      Assert.False(NotSet);
      Assert.True(isSet);
    }
  }
```